# jquery onclick doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code with a `link` , when clicking the link i want to do something, but i don't know why the click doesn't work, and the alert doesn't even fire

## jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#editConcept").on('click','ecAddLink',function(){
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getAllConcepts/TRUE",function(data){
            alert("William Roma");
            var options = '';
            options+="<option>Select Concept</option>";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getAllRelations/TRUE",function(data){
                var options2 = '';
                options2+="<option>Select Concept</option>";
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    options2 += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
                }
                $("#editConcept ul li:last").before('\
<li>\n\
    <p>\n\
        <label>Concept</label>\n\
        <select name="newConcepts[]">'+options+'</select>\n\
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>\n\
    </p>\n\
    <p>\n\
        <label>Relations</label>\n\
        <select name="newRelations[]">'+options2+'</select>\n\
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>\n\
        <a href="#" class="removeA">delete</a>\n\
    </p>\n\
</li>');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

## html code

```
<div id="editConcept" class="container">
    <form id="ecForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo URL; ?>Ontology/conceptEdit">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Select Concept</label>
                <select class="ConceptSelector1"></select>
                <span class="errorMessage"></span>
            </li> 
            <li id="ecOldRelations">
                <p>
                    <label>Old Relations</label>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li id="ecNewRelations">
                <label>New Relations</label>
                <a href="#" class="smallLink" id="ecAddLink">add new relations</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" class="button1" value="save"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>

the link has an id = ecAddLink
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are [missing the pound sign](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) in the selector: `#ecAddLink`. Most jQuery selectors are going to look like valid CSS strings, Prototype is the framework that accepts IDs without a pound sign if I remember correctly.

Besides that, I also really hate having full URLs in the code like that, you should try to go relative and if you can't store a webroot var globally. And I also am not a fan of so much HTML in a string (looks awful, hard to maintain/update, etc.). You should put the HTML in a hidden element in the page, or [inside a script tag](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/), easier that way IMO.

Comment: yes yes,  thank you , am so sorry , really 1 hour of trying finding the error , but never comes to my mind that , the wrong is easy like this

Comment: i am new to jquery and yes u right , i am too don't like to put html in string , thank you for ur advice about hidden elements , i will try to learn it

Comment: I believe absolute URLs you are talking about might be generated by the server-side.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Well, that was the comment for Paolo mostly but you can also consider this somehow :)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to place `#` for selecting element by ID:

```
$("#editConcept").on('click','#ecAddLink',function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: It happens very often. Be attentive ;)